# Regex to find second word in a list of paired words

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm trying to write a Sublime Text 3 syntax for EViews and need to find a regex that selects the second item in a list of pairs if and only if the first element of the pair appears in the beginning of the line (ignoring any leading whitespace).

I can do this for a single pair, say `if then`, with

```
^\s*if.+(then)
```

but it seems very clumsy to do it separately for each pair.

Surely there is a smarter way?

The full list of pairs is `if then`, `for to`, `to step`, `else if`, and `subroutine local`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/85kgtd/2):

```
\s*\bif\b.*?\b(then)\b|\s*\bfor\b.*?\b(to)\b|\s*\bto\b.*?\b(step)\b|\s*\belse\b.*?\b(if)\b|\s*\bsubroutine\b.*?\b(local)\b
```

Group 1 matches `then`, group 2 matches `to`, group 3 matches `step`, group 4 matches `if`, group 5 matches `local`, only if those are preceded by the right word.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^\s*if\s+\b(then)\b.*|^\s*for\s+\b(to)\b.*|^\s*to\s+\b(step)\b.*|^\s*else\s+\b(if)\b.*|^\s*subroutine\s+\b(local)\b.*
```

Make sure that dot matches new line is not selected